# Python mock patch not mocking the object

Tags: python, mocking, python-unittest, python-unittest.mock

I am using the python mocking library and I am not sure why I get this result. Why only the second one got mocked and not the first one? What's the best way to do it?

```py
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch, Mock

import requests
from requests import Session


def my_func():
    s = Session()
    print('my_func', type(s))


def my_func2():
    s = requests.Session()
    print('my_func2', type(s))


class Test(unittest.TestCase):

    @patch("requests.Session", new=Mock)
    def test1(self, *args):
        my_func()

    @patch("requests.Session", new=Mock)
    def test2(self, *args):
        my_func2()
```

Output

```
my_func <class 'requests.sessions.Session'>
my_func2 <class 'unittest.mock.Mock'>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a tricky nuance about Python namespaces.  In the first one, `my_func()`, you used just `Session` (after importing it into your module namespace with `from requests import Session`).  In `my_func2()` you used `requests.Session`.

`@patch('requests.Session')` is replacing `Session` *in* the `requests` module, so `requests.Session` will be the mock object.  But it does not replace every reference to `Session` in every module--in fact that would be very difficult to do in Python.

Really, on a basic level, what `patch()` is doing is just setting `requests.Session = Mock()`.  But to replace the reference to `Session` that's already in your module's global namespace it would have to set `globals()['Session'] = Mock()` as well.

In other words, you have to patch the object in the correct namespace.

If you have some module `foo.py` that contains:

```
from requests import Session

def my_func():
    s = Session()
    ...
```

then a separate test module `test_foo.py` in which you want to mock the `Session` class, you have to patch it in the namespace of `foo`, like:

```
import foo

@patch('foo.Session', ...)
def test_my_func():
    ...
```

Comment: Thank you very clear answer!